# Sorting Meta Objects By Date in liquid - Shopify

Tags: liquid, liquid-template, shopify-liquid

I'm trying to sort a meta object by date.

```
{% assign sorted_shows = shop.metaobjects.shows.values | sort: 'show.date' | reverse %}

{% for shows in sorted_shows %}
{{ shows.date }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

These are the results I get:

2024-02-09

2025-01-10

2024-02-01

2024-01-26

2024-02-16

any ideas?  I'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned Shopify has a glitch when it comes to sorting by Date. This fixes the issue.

```
{% assign sorted_shows = shop.metaobjects.shows.values | sort_natural: 'date' %} 
{% for shows in sorted_shows %} 
{{ shows.date }} <br> 
{% endfor %}
```